# Declare object, initialize as different type

Tags: c#

Is there a way to declare a global object, then initialize that object of a specific type depending on user input?

Such as what I've got:

```
  class Program{ 
  public myObject; // Trying to declare this globally
  public static object myObject; //Also tried
  public object myObject;  //Also tried with no luck on any


     static void getMode(string userInput){
         switch(userInput){
            case "a": myObject= new ClassA(); break;
            case "b": myObject= new ClassB(); break;
            default:  myObject= new ClassC(); break;
         }

         Console.WriteLine(myObject.getObjectString);
     }

      static void getInt(){
         Console.WriteLine(myObject.getInt.toString());
      }

  //More methods and stuff etc
  }
```

Each of the classes A B and C have, for example, the same methods.

However, the error Im getting is 'myObject' does not contain a definition for getObjectString and getInt. 
Also getting a 'no extension method' for both

The objects themselves do funky things, but simplified:

```
 public class ClassA{
      public string getObjectString{
         get{
            string retVal = "Class A string";   
            return retVal;
         }
      }
      public int32 getInt{
         get{
            int32 retVal = 42;   
            return retVal;
         }
      }
 } 
 public class ClassB{
      public string getObjectString{
         get{
            string retVal = "Class B string";   
            return retVal;
         }
      }
      public int32 getInt{
         get{
            int32 retVal = 7;   
            return retVal;
         }
      }
 }
```

I had a look through the Convert class, but I couldnt find anything useful. 
Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Read about interfaces and inheritance.

Comment: If those classes have the same methods, make them implement an interface and set your variable's type to that.

Comment: ref. [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx): "An interface contains definitions for a group of related functionalities that a class or a struct can implement."

Comment: Your ClassA and ClassB could, and probably should, be implemented as separate instances of the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interface.

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public string getObjectString{get;}
    public int32 getInt{get;}
}
```

Then make `ClassA` and `ClassB` implements `MyInterface` like so

```
public class ClassA : MyInterface{ ...
```

And use it this way

```
 public MyInterface myObject;



 static void getMode(string userInput){
     switch(userInput){
        case "a": myObject= new ClassA(); break;
        case "b": myObject= new ClassB(); break;
        default:  myObject= new ClassC(); break;
     }
```

You could also consider Inheritance.

Comment: IMOHO, inheritance should *only* be used when there is a specific need to share implementation.

Comment: Havnt used interfaces before, so didnt really know how they're used. But this seems work to what I need

Answer (score 0):

you could also return an object check and cast the returned value from your return method

```
static object GetMode(string userinput) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userinput)) {
        // use try catch in main method
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected a value in the userinput");
        // OR
        return new ClassC();
    }
    userinput = userinput.toLower();
    if (string.Equals("a")) {
        return new ClassA();
    } else if (string.Equals("b")) {
        return new ClassB();
    }
    return new ClassC();
}
```

and in your main method

```
var obj = GetMode(userinput);
if (obj is ClassA) {
    var classA = obj as ClassA;
    // do something with classA
    return;
}
if (obj is ClassB) {
    var classB = obj as ClassB;
    // do something with classB
    return;
}
if (obj is ClassC) {
    var classC = obj as ClassC;
    // do something with classC
    return;
}
```